# Awk - grouping by top three

Tags: awk

The data is in this format;-

```
South,London,5
South,Greenwich,7
South,Guildford,2
South,Maidstone,3
South,Oxted,4
North,Manchester,10
North,Leeds,7
North,Grimsby,9
North,Halifax,11
Midlands,Birmingham,16
Midlands,Coventry,10
Midlands,Walsall,15
Midlands,Rutland,1
```

I need an AWK program that sifts through and spits out the records to group by the second column but only printing the top three values thus;-

```
South,Greenwich,7
South,London,5
South,Oxted,4
North,Halifax,11
North,Manchester,10
North,Grimsby,9
Midlands,Birmingham,16
Midlands,Walsall,15
Midlands,Coventry,10
```

The actual file has far more regions/towns - any help?

Comment: I don't see where you are  "grouping" here. It looks like simple sorting by the 3rd column. Do you need to show more sample input and output to state your intention clearly? With this input and output, `sort -t, -k3,3nr file | head -3` will do it.

Comment: Original data file is a lot bigger .... such as North,Manchester,4,North,York,10,East,Norwich,2,East,Cambridge,4,West,Bristol,45,West,Yeovil,22 etc

Comment: I don’t see grouping and I don’t see anything done with the second column, only the third.

Comment: From the output I see that you mean top three of each category (the first field). This information should be in the question, not only the output and we have to find out what you mean...

Answer (score 4):

You can first sort it using `sort` command and then use `awk` to filter the top 3 for each category in `$1`:

```
sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3nr file | awk -F, 'n[$1]++<3'
```

Output:

```
Midlands,Birmingham,16
Midlands,Walsall,15
Midlands,Coventry,10
North,Halifax,11
North,Manchester,10
North,Grimsby,9
South,Greenwich,7
South,London,5
South,Oxted,4
```